# Controlling IIS BITS uploads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, bit

I'm running an IIS web site (built using ASP.NET/MVC) that among other things collects files from multiple agents that anonymously upload the files via BITS.

I need to make sure that only files uploaded from known sources as well as matching certain predefined file name pattern will be accepted by IIS. All other BITS upload attempts must be cancelled.

As I understand, BITS uses an ad hoc protocol over HTTP 1.1 using "BITS_POST" verb. So, ideally, I'd like to hook into IIS, analyze a BITS_POST request info and if it does not satisfy my pre-conditions, drop the request.

I've tried to create and register a filter implementing IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting, but it seems that my filter does not receive BITS_POST requests.

I'd be glad to hear if somebody have implemented similar BITS related solutions and how this was done. Anyway, other ideas are welcome too.

Regards,
Natan

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with BITS, frankly i dont know what is it.

What i usually do is such situations is implement an HTTP module. On its begin request event, you can iterate through incoming HTTP request data and decide to stop processing the request if data is not complying with requirements. You have full access to HttpContext.Current.Request object from HTTP module code.

With HTTP modules, you can execute .NET code even before entering the ASP.NET pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, Houssam. I'll give it a try and update with the results.
As for the BITS - it is Microsoft's Background Intelligent Transfer Service.

Comment: interesting! Thx for the info.